# UDF to calculate Frequency (Rank of values) in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to calculate frequency of a column value in a dataframe Spark I.e calculate Ranks of a highest occurring values.How do we define dataframe UDF for this in Spark ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at df.stat. Specifically you can get approx percentile and high frequency items.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a job for an `UDF`. I guess you want a simple aggregation:

```
df.groupBy("column").count.orderBy($"count".desc)
```

You can add rank with

```
withColumn(rank, rank.over(Window.orderBy($"count".desc")))
```

but it might be expensive with high cardinality.

```
df.groupBy("column").count.orderBy($"count".desc).rdd.zipWithIndex.toDF
```

might be an alternative, but it is not a true rank.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [inbuilt functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) if available rather than using `udf` functions as `udf` functions would require your data to be serialized and deserialized.

Using `partitionBy` in `Window` function should get your job done much more faster than `collect_list` and `count` on whole data in the column. Because `partitionBy` would let each groups to be distributed in spark worker nodes which is not the case in `collect_list` and `count` on whole dataset.

For test purpose following `dataframe` is created

```
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|35  |
|25  |
|25  |
|25  |
|19  |
|19  |
|19  |
|19  |
|70  |
+----+
```

You can simply use `partitionBy` in `Window` function, do the `counts` of each partitions and `concat` "Rank" in the counts as following

```
df.withColumn("Ranks", concat(lit("Rank "), count("col1").over(Window.partitionBy("col1"))))
```

You should get your desired output

```
+----+------+
|col1|Ranks |
+----+------+
|19  |Rank 4|
|19  |Rank 4|
|19  |Rank 4|
|19  |Rank 4|
|35  |Rank 1|
|25  |Rank 3|
|25  |Rank 3|
|25  |Rank 3|
|70  |Rank 1|
+----+------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks Ramesh ! nicely explained but what would be the substitute for collect_list here because I can have multiple values sharing the same rank, like Rank 1 in your example.

Comment: If I understand correctly how window functions work, doing the partitionBy would first cause a shuffle for everything and then do the count one after another for all rows. On the other hand collect_list would collect the actual values and shuffle just them giving one array for the whole thing. Therefore I believe that groupBy + count should be faster than partitionBy window